# Apache Nifi - What happens when you run getFile processor without any downstream processor

Tags: jvm, apache-nifi

I am a beginner to Apache Nifi and i want to move a file in my local filesystem from one location to another. When I used the `getFile` processor to move files from the corresponding input directory and started it, the file disappeared. I haven't connected it to a putFile processor. What exactly is happening here. Where does the file go if it disappears from the local directory i had placed it in. Also how can i get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetFile` has a property `Keep Source File`, if you have set to `true`, the file is not deleted after it has been copied from `Input Directory` to the Content Repository, default is `false` so this is the reason your files are deleted and you must have set `success` relation for auto termination otherwise `GetFile` won't run without any downstream connection. Your files have been discarded. Not sure whether this will work, but try the Data Provenance option and replay content.

Have a look at this -  [GetFile Official Doc](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GetFile/index.html) and [Replaying a FlowFile](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDF3/HDF-3.5.2/using-dataflow-provenance-tools/content/replaying-a-flowfile.html)